# Initialize dialog using automation script in maximo

Tags: maximo

I have a dialog which is mapped to a non persistent object. I need to display the list of records in the dialog using an automation script. I have tried to achieve this using setWhere() however it does not work.

```
receiptInputSet =MXServer.getMXServer().getMboSet("ABC", MXServer.getMXServer().getUserInfo("TEST"))
poLineNum="1"
siteID=mbo.getOwner().getString("SITEID")
receiptInputSet.setWhere("polinenum ='"+poLineNum+"' and SITEID='"+siteID+"'")
receiptInputSet.reset()
```

Answer (score 0):

You do not have information on the automation script - launch points, etc - and whether the non-persistent object is a custom object.

Are you trying to display data related to the non-persistent record shown in the dialog?